# I am trying to parse a non-standard rss feed with Powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell, rss, pinterest

My Pinterest feed truncates the RSS title to 20 characters and I need to parse out the "img src" and the longer text at the end of description.

My very simple code works, but I cannot figure out how to make my new title say "Why You’ve Got to Have an #Elevator #Pitch - #marketing"

```
$feed = [xml](New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://pinterest.com/bigoals365/feed.rss')

$feed.rss.channel.Item  | select title, link, description | Out-GridView
```

I have also tried Invoke-WebRequest and that works for the basic retrieval but the parsing of description has me stumped.

My feed looks like this (one line of the RSS):

```
<item><title>Why You’ve Got to Ha</title><link>http://pinterest.com/pin/329888741425045427/</link> <description> &lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/329888741425045427/"&gt;&lt; img src="http://media-cache-lt0.pinterest.com/192x/bd/5e/7c/bd5e7cd628c21313d835a4e5c89d28ee.jpg"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; Why You’ve Got to Have an #Elevator #Pitch - #marketing&lt;/p&gt; </description> <pubDate>Wed, 06 Mar 2013 21:59:55 +0000</pubDate><guid>http://pinterest.com/pin/329888741425045427/ </guid></item>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this way?

```
$feed.rss.channel.item | %{ 
   if ($_.description -match '.*<img src="([^"]+)".*<p>(.*)</p>') { 
      $_.title = $matches[2];
      $_.link = $matches[1] 
   } 
   $_ 
} | select title, link, description | Out-GridView
```

Hope this helps

/Fredrik

Comment: This answer worked best for getting the img and the full title. Really awesome! Thanks Fridden so much! And you help too Andy :}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
$feed.rss.channel.Item | 
    select -Property link, description, @{
        n = 'title'
        e = {[regex]::Matches($_.description, '<p>(.+?)</p>')[1].Groups[1].Value}
     } | ogv
```

This uses a hash table with the n (name) and e (expression) keys create a custom property.